# Hide dates in fullcalendar daygridweek

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I use a fullcalendar in my task at work and my goal is to set a fullcalendar as a timetable. I am almost done, the last problem is how to hide the date above each day cell and also display here long day name (like Monday, Thursday, etc...) I haven't found any solution out there on GitHub neither on the official fullcalendar documentation. Can anyone help me, please? Thank you

Current Fullcalendar settings

```
  <FullCalendar 
    plugins={[dayGridPlugin]} 
    initialView="dayGridWeek" 
    headerToolbar={false} 
    height={200}
    firstDay={1} 
  />
```

You can find the same fullcalendar component right here
https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-fiddle-forked-o72luh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Current state

[image]

The result I want

[image]

Comment: For the header format, I'm not sure why you couldn't find it in the documentation? It's right here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayHeaderFormat

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much. To be honest, I  found the fullcalendar docs a little bit confusing and I really appreciate your help. Feel free to post this as answer, I would like to give you some extra reputation :thumbup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you need is here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayHeaderFormat

```
dayHeaderFormat: { weekday: 'long' }
```

would be the correct setting for what you want. (This is vanilla JS syntax, but you can easily change it to react syntax, the point is the docs location and the setting value.)

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/LYmKPpd